# Parse HTML in a String

Tags: java

I have many string with html markup like that:

```
<font face='verdana'>A great project with many companies
A <b>plumber</b> company as external.
An <i>electricity</i> company.
And a security guard <u><i><b>during 2 weeks </b></i></u>.
</font>
```

Me, for each markup I want a new string with contents and markup, in my exemple it will be:

```
string1 = "A great project with many companies
A"

string2 = "<b>plumber</b>"

string3 = " company as external.
An"

string4 = "<i>electricity</i>"

string5 = " company.
And a 

string6 = "<font color='FF6600'>security </font>"

string7 = "guard"

string8 = "<u><i><b>during 2 weeks </b></i></u>"

string9 = "."

string10 = "</font>"
```

The first `<font face='verdana'>`and the last `</font>` can be deleted.

I've tried with the matcher method but the result wasn't exactly what I want, or maybe my regex wasn't good.
I've tried also to search first beginning tag and the first closing tag which corresponds but it's didn't work because all font tag (`<font color='FF6600'>` and ` have the same closing tag);.

Comment: Forget using regular expressions. Use an HTML Parser.

Comment: You should use a HTML parser to parse HTML, regex is not suitable. It might "work" for certain small chunks of HTML but it's not a good approach.

Comment: Look around Jsoup

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3742598) and use a DOM parser instead

Comment: Just to be precise: it is simply not possible to parse **arbitrary** HTML input using regular expressions technically. And as you already intend to do more complex things, dont waste your time with regular expressions.

Comment: Ok so I need to use Jsoup, but event with Jsoup I don't know how to do that

Comment: Have a look at the jsoup [docs](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/introduction/parsing-a-document), it's pretty straight-forward.

Comment: The problem is it solved with your Jsoup code ? Let us know